# PostgreSQL inserts table data into SERIAL PRIMARY KEY field

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker, csv, airflow

postgres tries to insert csv values into the SERIAL PRIMARY KEY field and I don't understand why.

I get the following error message when copying a .csv to my postgres:

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: "0.0"
CONTEXT:  COPY raw_data, line 2, column transaction_id: "0.0"
```

While the error message is quite clear, I do not understand why postgres tries to do this.

I have the following CREATE TABLE statement:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS raw_data (
    transaction_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    transaction_time NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V1 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V2 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V3 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V4 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V5 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V6 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V7 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V8 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V9 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V10 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V11 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V12 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V13 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V14 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V15 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V16 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V17 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V18 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V19 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V20 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V21 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V22 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V23 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V24 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V25 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V26 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V27 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V28 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    Amount NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    Class NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    Datetime_write VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

with the following .csv columns which do not include transaction_id as this is created by postgres (if I understood SERIAL correctly).

`Time,V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10,V11,V12,V13,V14,V15,V16,V17,V18,V19,V20,V21,V22,V23,V24,V25,V26,V27,V28,Amount,Class,datetime_write_query`

Copy command:

```
COPY raw_data
FROM '/maindata/df_raw.csv'
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

It looks like postgres is trying to insert `Time` (which is a float) into column `transaction_id` and I don't understand why. What am I doing wrong?
Additional info: I am using Docker and Airflow in my setup.

Thank you already!

Comment: If there are less columns in the CSV file then the table then you need to provide a column list to the `COPY` command to get the file columns and the table columns to match up. As of now `COPY` is taking the first file column as `transaction_id` and going from there across the table columns. See [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).

Comment: I should have added that on import of a CSV file `HEADER` just ignores the first line of the file. It does not use the field names in the header to match those in the table.

Comment: Ah look your first comment is the knowledge I was missing, thank you!